# Error installing kubectl on self hosted gitlab on ubuntu

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubectl

I have installed Gitlab on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Gitlab is working fine. 
Now, I am trying to install kubectl on the same machine. But getting an issue on command:

```
$ kubectl cluster-info dump
```

---

```
error: serializer for text/html; charset=utf-8 doesn't exist
```

Comment: Which guide you followed to install k8s? Have you tried dumping it to a file `kubectl cluster-info dump --output-directory=/path/to/cluster-state`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `kubectl` is talking to something else that is not your `kube-apiserver`.  Make sure your `~/.kube/config` file looks something like this and points to the right `kube-apiserver`:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <REDACTED>
    server: https://10.10.10.1:6443 <== This needs to point to the right kube-apiserver address
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    namespace: default
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: <REDACTED>
    client-key-data: <REDACTED>
```